# array format issue PHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I want to change an array format according to my needs. When I fetch data from a database using cakephp `find('all')` method, it returns something that is not in the format that I expected.

My resultant array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DriverLocation] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 15
                    [dispensary_id] => 1
                    [driver_id] => 85
                    [zip_code_id] => 43
                    [created] => 2015-05-20 12:25:34
                )

            [ZipCode] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 43
                    [province_id] => 3846
                    [city] => Rohtak
                    [zip_code] => 15478
                    [status] => active
                )

            [UserProfile] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Arman
                    [last_name] => Kumar
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DriverLocation] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 19
                    [dispensary_id] => 1
                    [driver_id] => 43
                    [zip_code_id] => 42
                    [created] => 2015-05-20 12:37:12
                )

            [ZipCode] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 42
                    [province_id] => 3846
                    [city] => Rohtak
                    [zip_code] => 30215
                    [status] => active
                )

            [UserProfile] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Pawan
                    [last_name] => Kumar
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [DriverLocation] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 20
                    [dispensary_id] => 1
                    [driver_id] => 83
                    [zip_code_id] => 42
                    [created] => 2015-05-20 12:37:28
                )

            [ZipCode] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 42
                    [province_id] => 3846
                    [city] => Rohtak
                    [zip_code] => 30215
                    [status] => active
                )

            [UserProfile] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Ramesh
                    [last_name] => Saini
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [DriverLocation] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 26
                    [dispensary_id] => 1
                    [driver_id] => 83
                    [zip_code_id] => 43
                    [created] => 2015-05-20 12:43:59
                )

            [ZipCode] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 43
                    [province_id] => 3846
                    [city] => Rohtak
                    [zip_code] => 15478
                    [status] => active
                )

            [UserProfile] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Ramesh
                    [last_name] => Saini
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [DriverLocation] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 41
                    [dispensary_id] => 1
                    [driver_id] => 83
                    [zip_code_id] => 6
                    [created] => 2015-05-21 05:23:53
                )

            [ZipCode] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [province_id] => 3846
                    [city] => Whittier
                    [zip_code] => 90607
                    [status] => active
                )

            [UserProfile] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Ramesh
                    [last_name] => Saini
                )

        )

)
```

And I want to convert it into something like this:

```
Array
(
    [DriverLocation] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [dispensary_id] => 1
            [driver_id] => 85
        )

    [ZipCode] => Array
        (
            [zip_code] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 15478
                )

            [city] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Rohtak
                )

        )

    [UserProfile] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Arman
            [last_name] => Kumar
        )

)
Array
(
    [DriverLocation] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [dispensary_id] => 1
            [driver_id] => 43
        )

    [ZipCode] => Array
        (
            [zip_code] => Array
                (

                    [0] => 30215
                )

            [city] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Rohtak

                )

        )

    [UserProfile] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Pawan
            [last_name] => Kumar
        )

)
Array
(
    [DriverLocation] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [dispensary_id] => 1
            [driver_id] => 83
        )

    [ZipCode] => Array
        (
            [zip_code] => Array
                (

                    [0] => 30215
                    [1] => 15478
                    [2] => 90607

                )

            [city] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Rohtak
                    [1] => Rohtak
                    [2] => Whittier
                )

        )

    [UserProfile] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Ramesh
            [last_name] => Saini
        )

)
```

Filter according to `DriverLocation->driver_id`

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do that? The original format has all the information, easily accessible. Your proposed format spreads array elements across an unknown number of variables and adds nothing to the readability of any code you might write for it.

Comment: thanks for comment. but problem comes when i want to show this data on a webpage using table then it generate duplicate rows. that i don't want.

Comment: If you by chance get the output like that, traversing through the array would then become a nightmare. Just saying.

Comment: @ManishKumar - Well, then why not alter how you are outputting the data to the web page?

Comment: Add your table code, remove the 'wanted-new-format-of-the-array' code.

Comment: how to change this array to my liking ?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Show your attempts

Comment: It looks like your problem is not with the format of the array but what you want to do with it! As @RST says post the table code. You will be much more successful with Cake if you work with its conventions. If you really must manipulate the array take a look at CakePHP's Hash library: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/hash.html.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that these arrays are exactly the same, except that you put every "record" of `DriverLocation` in its own variable. The idea here is that you receive the data from the `DriverLocation` Model in the fictional controller and put it in a variable; for example:

```
$allDriverLocations = $this->DriverLocation->find("all");
```

Now `$allDriverLocations` contains the first one of your mentioned arrays.
Next step is to pass it to the view:

```
$this->set(compact("allDriverLocations"));
```

And now to create a table in the associated view you should iterate through `$allDriverLocations`:

```
<table>
<tbody>

<?php
// Loop through the array with a foreach
foreach($allDriverLocations as $driverLocation){
    // Create the table row here using the HtmlHelper.
    // If you want to reach "Rohtak" for example, you use $driverLocation["Zipcode"]["city"] to print it.
}
?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

I wouldn't know why you should not follow Cake's easy conventions...